# Join map keys, values to a string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

What is the best way for me to join a map's key, value to a string

for example:

```
>> keySet =   {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'};
>> valueSet = [327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4];
>> mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet)
```

I would like to convert the `mapObj` to string like

```
'Jan=327.2, Fab=368.2, Mar=197.6, Apr=178.4'
```

I've tried using the library `foreach`[link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28630-foreach-for-containers-map/content/foreach.m) to loop through, to loop through keys, values but I think there might be a better solution than this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
   c = [keys(mapObj); values(mapObj)];   
   outStr = sprintf('%s=%.1f, ', c{:});
   outStr(end-1:end) = []; % remove last comma and space
```

Gives:

```
outStr =

    Apr=178.4, Feb=368.2, Jan=327.2, Mar=197.6
```

If you want to have the same order of keys as when creating the Map, you can do:

```
   c = [keySet; values(mapObj, keySet)];   
   outStr = sprintf('%s=%.1f, ', c{:});
   outStr(end-1:end) = []; % remove last comma
```

This gives:

```
outStr =

   Jan=327.2, Feb=368.2, Mar=197.6, Apr=178.4
```

Comment: @LiJung I extended the anwser for case when order of months in string should be same as that used when creating the map.

Comment: thanks, for further question how about adding a if statement in values, if it is a string render `%s=%s`, thanks for helping! :)

Comment: @LiJung Not sure what you mean by adding `if` statement. Where would you want to add this statement?

Comment: sorry I found out I'm asking a stupid question. I'm pretty new in Matlab.

Comment: @LiJung Ok, no worries.